# departing the US after arriving with ESTA

Tags: esta, dual-nationality

How does this work? i have dual Nigerian-British citizenship and i want to travel to the US from Nigeria.
if I travel to the US with a british passport ( with ESTA of course) i will need to give the airline details of my UK Passport.

When departing, the airline will need my pp details on checkin and i provide my Nigerian pp details as it wont accept my british pp (saying i will need a visa).

how will the US know that the same person who entered with british pp is the same one departing with a Nigerian one?

Comment: You give the airline both passports.

Comment: thanks...this surely helps ...so i show the airline my Nigerian passport when flying from the US to Nigeria and of course present my British with ESTA when i arrive in the US. Quick Question though...seems the US don't stamp passports when passengers are departing. Do they solely rely on airline data for departing passengers then?

Comment: @Jigga yep they do. And no, you show both passports when leaving. They will know they have to register 'British you', as whom you entered, as leaving and that you're allowed to enter Nigeria on the Nigerian passport. They have ways to know both passports belong to the same person, but they may not use them for linking people entering and leaving and you rather be safe than sorry, right?

Comment: Right. That is why you give the airline both of your passport numbers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't have my glasses on so everything is a bit blurry, but is the US with their nonexistent exit checks actually covered in that question?

Comment: @J.Constantine Yes, and this situation is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Worst case scenario is you check your [I-94 record](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94) online after you leave, and if our mess of an exit tracking system managed to miss your departure, you send them proof that you left like a boarding pass stub and they'll fix the records.